# How can i set a default "content" which indicates the behaviour of Ai in createChatCompletion, while using vercel ai 'useChat' hook [Next.js]?

Tags: next.js13, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Let's suppose i want to set default behaviour of chatGpt's api to "Behave like a teacher", normally i would do it by using "content" property, but since i use useChat hook i have "messages: messages" and i'm not quite sure how to get "messages" to work with "content".

Picture of my route.ts file:
[route.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgIiY.png)

Any suggestions on how to solve it?